# Very strange behavior using OpenMP

Tags: c++, opencv, openmp

Right now, I am constantly getting bad results with OpenMP, so it must be something I do not understand. At the moment I have very strange behavior on a for-loop which runs without OpenMP. This is the outline of the program:

```c++
void computeAandB(Xi, XiDX, XiDY, XiDZ, depthImg){

    double tstart = omp_get_wtime();

    cv::Mat Error = rayCast(Xi, depthImg);
    cv::Mat ErrorDX = rayCast(XiDX, depthImg);
    cv::Mat ErrorDY = rayCast(XiDY, depthImg);
    cv::Mat ErrorDZ = rayCast(XiDZ, depthImg);

   float A1 = 0;
   float b1 = 0;
   for (i = 0; i < rows; ++i){
       for (j = 0; j < cols; ++j){
           V0 = Error(i,j);
           V0DX = ErrorDX(i,j);
           V0DY = ErrorDY(i,j);
           V0DZ = ErrorDZ(i,j);
           VectorXf grad = computeGrad(V0,V0DX,V0DY,V0DZ);
           A1 += grad(0);
           b1 += grad(1);
       }
   }

  double t2 = omp_get_wtime();
  cout<<"Time for everything: "<< t2 - t1 <<endl;
```

When I run everything in serial, each raycast takes approximately 0.8 seconds, and the summation 1.1 seconds.

When I run the for-loop in rayCast in parallel using OpenMP, it runs in about 0.2 seconds, but then the loop after the four calls to rayCast takes about 115 seconds! That is not even using openMp. I do not see any logic in this, why would the loop afterwards be so slow? At the moment I am just timing the code as written above, i.e. between all rayCasts and the for-loop.

The images I get from rayCast all looks ok, so that function works.

This is the rayCast function:

```c++
cv::Mat ModelTracker::rayCast(const Eigen::VectorXf &Xi, const cv::Mat &depthImg)
{
    LieAlgebra::LieAlgebra Lie;
    cv::Mat tmp = cv::Mat::zeros(depthImg.rows, depthImg.cols, CV_32FC1);
    Eigen::Matrix3f R = Lie.getRotation(Xi);
    Eigen::Vector3f t = Lie.getTranslation(Xi);
    int i, j;
#pragma omp parallel for private (i,j) shared(R,t,tmp)
    for (i = 0; i < depthImg.rows; ++i){
        for (j = 0; j < depthImg.cols; ++j){
            const float z = depthImg.at<float>(i, j);
            if (!isnan(z)){
                Eigen::Vector3f pLocal = reproject3f(j, i, z);
                Eigen::Vector3f pGlobal = R*pLocal + t;
                Eigen::Vector3f ray = (pGlobal - t);
                float pointDist = ray.norm();
                ray.normalize();
                /*          cout << "norm ray" << endl;
                            cout << ray.norm() << endl;
                            getchar();*/
                float d = traverseRay(ray, t,pointDist);
                //cout << "d: " << d << endl;
                //cout << "t + d*ray: " << t + d*ray << endl;
                //cout << " t + pointDist*ray: " << t + pointDist*ray << endl;
                //cout << endl;
                //cout << "pGlobal: " << pGlobal << endl;
                //getchar();
                float err = (pointDist - d);
                //float SDF = interpolate(pGlobal);
                //cout << "err  SDF: "<< err << "  " << SDF << endl;
                //getchar();
                if (fabs(err) > RAYTHRESHOLD){
                    float sign = err / fabs(err);
                    err = sign*RAYTHRESHOLD;
                }
                tmp.at<float>(i, j) = (err);
            }
            else {
                tmp.at<float>(i, j) = NAN;
            }
        }
    }
    return tmp;
}
```

A strange thing is that it works as it should on my other computer, for the moment at least...

Note: Some comments about making `i` and `j` private, I have made both private, but it does not help on my computer at school.

Sorry, forgot to write about the OS and hardware. It is a window 7 distribution with 6 physical cores and I am running Visual Studio 2013 with OpenMP enabled and optimization that favours fast code.

Update: 
I just rebooted the computer and ran the program again. The first seven times computeAandB took 1.8 seconds in total. Then for the next four took 91 seconds each! Then it went back to 1.8 seconds per call. Can it be some setting that is wrong? I do run it in Release mode, but can it be some other setting which makes it run in debug sometimes?

Another strange thing is that if I use OpenMP in rayCast, and then in computeAandB do this:

```c++
    cv::Mat Error = rayCast(Xi, depthImg);
    cv::Mat ErrorDX = rayCast(XiDX, depthImg);
    cv::Mat ErrorDY = rayCast(XiDY, depthImg);
    cv::Mat ErrorDZ = rayCast(XiDZ, depthImg);
    cv::imshow("Error",Error);
    cv::waitKey(0)
```

so that I show the image and wait for a key to be pressed before the serial for-loop. Then the serial for-loop works as expected. It does not take 130 seconds to compute. Seems like something from openMP is left and causes problem?

Comment: Can we see where/how you use OpenMP? Also how are you timing this?

Comment: You must define all your loop iterators as `private`. So it should be `private(i, j) shared(R,t,tmp)`.

Comment: According to a tutorial it is only necessary to declare the inner variable as private: http://supercomputingblog.com/openmp/tutorial-parallel-for-loops-with-openmp/ I do not think that is the problem.

Comment: Just declare the loop indices the C99 way to be sure they are private.  And it never hurts to be explicit since, if you are wrong, the consequent are dire.

Comment: What compile options are you using(`e.g. -O3 -fopenmp` with GCC). Are you compiling with optimization enabled? What compiler is this? What is the OS. What is the hardware (if Linux what does `cat /proc/cpuinfo` show)? How many processors and cores?

Comment: It is visual studio 2013, win 7 with optimization favoring speed.

Comment: I saw your updated your answer with the info. But I still don't think there is enough information to figure out your problem. You need to do some more debugging on your own or give us more clues.

Comment: Are you 100% you're getting the same result with wan without OpenMP?